# python write list to csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I have this code for trying to write list (of lists) to a csv, where each item (which is a list) should be written as a new csv row:

```
    resultFile = open("E:/tmobile/CR_Accuracy/cycle7/pp/output.csv",'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    for item in result:
      wr.writerow([item,])
```

For some weird reason the csv file is empty after code executes and finishes.
An example to few of the list item copies from a 'Watch' with PyCharm:

```
    (7031482579417L, 'Payment', 'Yes', 'Yes - Both')
    (7031482579417L, 'Rate Plan OR Plan Fit Analysis', 'Yes', 'Yes - System')
    (7031482579417L, 'Credits and Adjustments', 'Yes', 'Yes - Both')
```

Comment: did you do `resultFile.close()`?

Answer (score 1):

If the list is a list of tuples, just pass `item`, not `item` inside a list. In addition to that, as theharshes comment, make sure that you closed the file.

```
with open("E:/tmobile/CR_Accuracy/cycle7/pp/output.csv",'wb') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    for item in result:
        wr.writerow(item)
```

or more shortly with [`csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows):

```
with open("E:/tmobile/CR_Accuracy/cycle7/pp/output.csv",'wb') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have given doesn't appear to close the file. It may be that python never got around to flushing the file before the program ends. If that is the case calling resultFlie.close() should fix it.